# Difficulty Sending Selected Rows from WPF DataGrid to SQL Table

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I'm facing an issue with my WPF application where I need to send selected rows from a `DataGrid` to a `SQL` database table. Despite implementing the necessary logic, the methods responsible for handling the selection and sending the data are not being triggered.
Unreachable Methods: The methods (`CanSendSelectedRows` and `SendSelectedRowsToSQL`) responsible for handling the selection and sending the data to the SQL database table are not being reached when expected.
here are these methods:

```cs
//constructor
 public DataGridViewModel()
        {
            
            DataGridItems = new ObservableCollection<States>();
            SelectedItems = new ObservableCollection<States>();
            
            LoadDataFromDatabase();

            
            SendSelectedRowsToSQLCommand = new RelayCommand(SendSelectedRowsToSQL, CanSendSelectedRows);
         }

public ObservableCollection<States> SelectedItems
        {
            get => _selectedItems;
            set
            {
                _selectedItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItems));

            }
        }

public ICommand SendSelectedRowsToSQLCommand { get;  set; }
private bool CanSendSelectedRows(object parameter)
        {
           //return true;
            // Ensure that SelectedItems is not null and contains at least one item
           return SelectedItems != null && SelectedItems.Any();
        }

public void SendSelectedRowsToSQL(object parameter)
        {
            using (var context = new DbProjectEntities())

            {
                foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
                {
                    context.orderedStateTbl.Add(new orderedStateTbl
                    {
                        orderStateId = item.StateID,
                        oStateName = item.StateName
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

The `button` responsible for triggering the action is always enabled, even before any rows are selected in the `DataGrid`.

```xml
<Button Content="Send Selected Rows" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Margin="0,0,0,20"
                Command="{Binding SendSelectedRowsToSQLCommand }"/>
```

and finally I set `dataContext` of my `View` in code behind as follow

```cs
            InitializeComponent();
            _viewmodel = new DataGridViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewmodel;
```

I apologize for my very simple question. could anyone help me what is my mistake or what should I do?

Comment: `DbProjectEntities` is your implementation of EF `DbContext`?

Comment: yes. I use EF `database First`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're just not saving your changes to the database. Imagine you have a `Select All` button in your software, and a user selects 10,000 rows at a time. How those rows should be saved in your opinion? When you're calling `DbContext.DbSet.Add`? - No, that's not how it works, you're going to overload your DB with 10,000 queries.

Instead, Microsoft designed `DbContext` to follow the repository pattern, which means you're keeping all the changes in memory, until explicit save/commit invocation.

Thus, you're method should have one additional row:

```
public void SendSelectedRowsToSQL(object parameter)
{
    using (var context = new DbProjectEntities())
    {
        foreach (var item in SelectedItems)
        {
            context.orderedStateTbl.Add(new orderedStateTbl
            {
                orderStateId = item.StateID,
                oStateName = item.StateName
            });
        }

        context.SaveChanges(); // Here is the commit transaction call
    }
}
```

Furthermore, all the DB queries are I/O operations and since that - it is recommended to do the querying methods asynchronous. So I'd suggest you to redesign your method a bit:

```
public async void SaveAsync(object parameter)
{
    using var context = new DbProjectEntities();

    context.orderedStateTbl.AddRange(
        SelectedItems.Select(item => new orderedStateTbl
        {
            orderStateId = item.StateID,
            oStateName = item.StateName
        }));

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```